# What does this term G+G'->G' mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photons, plane-wave

In [this document](http://www.phys.ubbcluj.ro/~emil.vinteler/nanofotonica/PWM/pwmmanual_Guo.pdf), what does the line "Write $\vec{G}_i + \vec{G}_i' \rightarrow \vec{G}_i'$" after equation (25) actually mean?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means replace all instances of $G_i+G_i'$ with $G_i'$ (and likewise all instances of $G_i'$ with $G_i'-G_i$).

Comparing the equations above the comment and below it (i.e., Equations 25 and 26) should have told you as much.

Comment: Hmmmm... I understand that...but I would like to know the physical significance and interpretation about why and how could that line be written??

Comment: It is just a relabeling as far as I can tell... In that case, it does not carry any physical significance